# Google Earth Questions: Making Outside Pages Appear in Google Earth and A Button That Follows

Tags: kml, google-earth

Good morning, eveyrone

I'm working on an application using Google Earth and I had two questions.

The first question involves the pop up window. I want to get an external website to appear in this bubble. I can either hardcode the website into the description of the placemark or use an iFrame. Are there any other options I can use to get a website into Google Earth?

Second question: I want to ensure that the user, at all times while using my kml, has access to certain buttons. Is there a way without querying web application every few seconds to ensure that the button remains available to the user?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to you first question is no - other than loading the html directly or using an IFRAME there is no way to display markup in the content balloons.

I am not sure what you mean in you second question, are you developing a web-based application using the Google Earth Plugin - or a kml layer for use in the google earth application. Either way you should not have to query anything to make sure a button is visible.